# Vim search and replace "/" only from string between round bracket

Tags: gvim, linux

I have string lets say

```
count number of elecment when tra(XYixe0/en_in/old)='mid/2' rise='corse/2'
```

I want to replace / from (XYixe0/en_in/old) to .

My output string should look like

```
count number of elecment when tra(XYixe0.en_in.old)='mid/2' rise='corse/2'
```

In summary, I want vim search / only on string which is inside () and replace / by .

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See also my answer on the duplicate about using Visual mode to mark the part where you want to replace and the `\%V` marker to only replace inside the last Visual mode marked block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way is to use a sub-replace-expression, `\=`:

```
:%s/([^)]*)/\=substitute(submatch(0),'\/','.','g')/
```

The `:s/([^)]*)/{replacement}/` will match a pair of parens, `([^)]*)`. The `{replacement}` is `\={expr}`. Where `{expr}` will be a vimscript expression to be evaluated. In this case a substitution over the entire match, `submatch(0)`, matching on `\/` and replacing with `.` for the entire string, `g`.

For more help see:

```
:h sub-replace-expression
:h :s
:h substitute()
:h submatch()
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not perfect since you have to run it multiple times to get every slash, but that's not too big of a problem:

```
:%s/(.*\zs\/\ze.*)/./g
```

This will replace *one* slash inside of parenthesis with a dot. To get it to replace all of them, you could then run something like

```
5@:
```

to get all of them replaced. (Adjust 5 to be as big as needed).

Answer (score 1):

So this is a bit of a hack. If your inside the parenthesis

```
di(mmo^R"^[:s/\//./g^Mv$hxdd`m"-P
```

`di(` delete inside the parenthesis

`mm` make a mark so you can get back to your original position

`^R"` paste the " register into buffer from insert mode, that is ctrl+r

`^[` is escape

`:s/\//./g^M` this is the substitution with `^M` = enter

`v$hx` mark and delete your change this will also put it in the `-` register

`dd` will delete the line

`m that is backtick m (couldn't format that properly) which will take you back to the mark

`"-P` insert text from `-` register in before current char

Answer (score 0):

The shortest path, not requiring repeat runs, is probably the (in)famous sub-replace expression.

A recent q&a asked [a similar question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/20704/how-to-run-a-substitute-command-on-only-a-certain-part-of-the-line/20706#20706) regarding doing a replacement on just a portion of a line. In fact, they also wanted to operate on text inside parentheses. (This could arguably be considered a duplicate question...but I won't argue that here.) I posted a pretty extensive answer on using sub-replace expressions which is a method for running an arbitrary Vim expression as the replacement part of a substitution.

Some people find this approach complicated but I don't think it's too bad once you break it down....which I tried my best to do.

Briefly, either of these will work for your question...

```
:s#(\([^)]\+\))#\='(' . substitute(submatch(1), '/', '.', 'g') . ')'#

:s#(\zs\([^)]\+\)\ze)#\=substitute(submatch(1), '/', '.', 'g')#
```

And there are other variations, too. These are a little stretched out for readability (maybe). It also depends on how conservative/error-proof you want the solution to be.

Rather than repeat here what I said in that answer I suggest you read the original: [How to run a substitute command on only a certain part of the line](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/20704/how-to-run-a-substitute-command-on-only-a-certain-part-of-the-line/20706#20706)