# Is it possible to apply substitutions on parts of lines, instead of whole lines?

Tags: substitute

I have some text like this.

```
    a x="true" i q={1}
```

That is, a line of text prefixed with 4 space characters. Then letters with spaces in between.

I'd like to transform the text to this

```
    a
x="true"
i
q={1}
```

(So keep the 4 spaces at the beginning and replace every next space with a line break.)

First, I tried `s/ /\r/g`, but then I realized that substitution also replaces the leading 4 spaces. However, I want to keep the 4 leading spaces.

Is there a way to use substitutions on parts of lines, instead of whole lines?

Comment: For that specific example this seems like an easy route: `:s/a /a\r/g`...or if the letters can be other than 'a'... `:s/\w /&\r/g'

Comment: Ooh, cool. Didn't know about `\w` and `&`!

Comment: They're both pretty common, especially `\w`...do yourself a favor and read sections 4,5,6 in the pattern.txt reference (`:h pattern`). So many goodies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Jump to the end for the simplest solution. I decided to thumb my nose at the KISS principle for a while before snapping out of it and posting the easy answer.* :P

At least three ways come to mind to handle this.

The first uses the `%v` pattern "atom" (see [`:h /\%v`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#/%5C%v)). This is used to pin the search after/before a column number. For example this matches all text up to column 17: `/^.*\%17v`

We'll use it to skip over the opening four spaces and then substitute line feeds for every space afterwards:

```
s/\%>4v /\r/g
```

Another option is to use "look arounds". Specifically a "negative lookbehind" (`:h /\@<!`). We want to change all spaces to line feed except for those that are at the beginning of the line or separated from the beginning of the line by only whitespace.

```
s/\%(^\s*\)\@<!\s/\r/g
```

So that says to match any whitespace, `\s`, *as long as there is no match preceding it* (`\@<!`) made up of the beginning of the line plus optional whitespace characters (`\%(^\s*\)`). This actually will work for any length of opening indent.

Note that lookaround expressions don't actually consume any of the target string. This explains: [/zero-width](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2fzero-width)

These answers are specifically targeting your stated use case (four-space indent followed by the "sentence" to modify). But the subject asks a more general question ("apply substitution on parts of lines"). That question has been asked before and you can find some more generalized discussion there: [How to run a substitute command on only a certain part of the line](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/20704/how-to-run-a-substitute-command-on-only-a-certain-part-of-the-line/20706#20706)

In fact, to understand my third solution I recommend you read my answer there. This approach is probably overkill for the relatively simple problem we're looking at here (though I maintain this isn't as complicated as some folks make it out to be). For the sake of thoroughness I give you the *sub-replace expression* solution:

```
s/^\s\+\zs\(.*\)/\=substitute(submatch(0), ' ', '\r', 'g')/
```

**Update:** Silly me, I left out the easiest solution. This despite the fact that I posted something similar in a comment above (though that was targeting an earlier, easier version of the question)...

```
s/\(\S\+\) /\1\r/g
```

That is, match every sequence of non-whitespace characters (`\S\+`) followed by a space (). Surround all but the space in a capturing group (`\(...\)`). Each occurrence of this pattern in the line will be replaced with the captured characters (`\1`) and then a line feed (`\r`).