# Vim decremental replace not working

Tags: substitute

I want to replace the lines :

```
https://www.dailymotion.com/video/whatever_1 # The Serie - S2 E4 - Grin and Bear It
https://www.dailymotion.com/video/whatever_2 # The Serie - S2 E3 - Betty's Wait Problem
https://www.dailymotion.com/video/whatever_3 # The Serie - S1 E21 - Secretaries Day
...
```

by these lines :

```
https://www.dailymotion.com/video/whatever_1 # The Serie - S2 E4 - whatever_79
https://www.dailymotion.com/video/whatever_2 # The Serie - S2 E3 - whatever_78
https://www.dailymotion.com/video/whatever_3 # The Serie - S1 E21 - whatever_77
...
```

So I tried different combinations of the following vim command :

```
:let i=79 | g/^http/s/\(S[0-9]\+ E[0-9]\+\).*$/\1 - whatever_\=i/ | let i=i-1
```

but none has worked and I got this instead :

```
https://www.dailymotion.com/video/whatever_1 # The Serie - S2 E4 - whatever_=i
https://www.dailymotion.com/video/whatever_2 # The Serie - S2 E3 - whatever_=i
https://www.dailymotion.com/video/whatever_3 # The Serie - S1 E21 - whatever_=i
```

Can you help me ?

Comment: There's more info on `\=` [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/20704/how-to-run-a-substitute-command-on-only-a-certain-part-of-the-line/20706#20706). And just for fun...you could have repaired the lines all ending in '=i' by doing a `Ctrl+V` select of the last column (cursor on firstline then `<c-v>}k$`) followed by `:s//79/ | norm! gvojg<c-v><c-x>` (For `<c-v>`, `<c-x>` here you should enter actual `Ctrl+V`/`Ctrl+X` chars).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `\=`, it needs to be at the start of the replacement, and the whole replacement expression becomes an expression.

You can use the `submatch()` function to access your backreferences, since `\1` will not work from a `\=` replacement expression.

After you do that, all you need is `" - whatever_".i` to produce the replacement using a string concatenation.

Putting it all together:

```
:let i=79 | g/^http/s/\(S[0-9]\+ E[0-9]\+\).*$/\=submatch(1)." - whatever_".i/ | let i=i-1
```

It's easier to do that if you don't need the backreference. In this particular case, you can easily avoid the backreference by using `\zs`, which marks the start of the match, the part that actually gets replaced:

```
:let i=79 | g/^http/s/S[0-9]\+ E[0-9]\+\zs.*$/\=" - whatever_".i/ | let i=i-1
```

Comment: @fibranden I do need the `\1`, is there a function replacement for `\1` which can be called after `\=` ?

Comment: @SebMa yes: see `:help submatch(`

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Incorporated the reference to `submatch()`. Also expanded on `\zs` to explain it a little better. In this exact case here, you *really* don't need to use backreferences... But it's possible you do elsewhere, where you might want to reorder things, so good to include that information too.

Comment: @filbranden Can you please also incorporate the `submatch(1)` solution in a second `g//s///` vim command ?

Comment: @SebMa done! Please take another look.