# Substitution within substitution? Replace with the result of a substitution operation on matched group

Tags: substitute

I would like to turn a list like this

```
these are
custom regex expressions 4
syntax? syntax
weird one 3
there are many many many many words in this line 3
```

into this

```
these are
custom {4}regex {4}expressions
syntax? syntax
weird {3}one
there {3}are {3}many {3}many {3}many {3}many {3}words {3}in {3}this {3}line
```

I know how to get rid of the trailing number ending

```
:%s/ \d\+$//
```

I know how to replace spaces

```
:s/ / {3}/g
```

but how do I combine these two? The second should only apply to lines that actually ended in a number, and use that number.

In my head this problem formed a "substitution in a substitution" thing, like this:

```
:%s/\(.\+\) \(\d\+\)$/\1.replace(' ', ' {\2}')/
```

But there is likely a better, VIM, way to solve this. Maybe my conceptualised solution is not supported.

Please how can I perform such operations?

Comment: Would something like this work? `:g/\d$/s/ /\=' {' . matchstr(getline('.'), '\d\+$') . '}'/g` This use a `:g` command to match only lines ending with w number and applies a substitution command using an expression composed of `' {` i.e the space and the first bracket concatenated with `matchstr(getline('.'), '\d\+$')` which gets the number at the end of the line. You'll probably need to clean up the remaining trailing digits with `:%s/\d\+$//`

Comment: Your instinct was kinda on the right track. In general, if you have a substitution problem that can be expressed along the lines of "match a pattern then within the matched string match another pattern [and substitute]" you're often going to need [sub-replace expressions](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/20704/how-to-run-a-substitute-command-on-only-a-certain-part-of-the-line/20706#20706) . That's what statox's suggestion is using.

Comment: @BLayer would you like to post an answer? Thanks to your link i've figured out the answer ought to be `:%s/\(.\+\) \(\d\+\)$/\=substitute(submatch(1), ' ', ' {' . submatch(2) . '}', 'g')/`

Comment: Cool. Glad it was that easy. Go ahead and post an answer yourself, if you'd like. Maybe an upvote for the answer that helped, though...? :)   If you'd prefer someone else answer then I'll do it.

Comment: @theonlygusti Please turn that into an answer! That's exactly correct, that's what I came here to post, but saw you got to it already. Cheers!

Comment: @theonlygusti And yeah, `substitute()` in a `:substitute` is what I'd say is the best way to do "substitution within substitution".  It's pretty standard, you'll find that same answer in many similar questions as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to B Layer's guidance in the comments and [his answer here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/20706/9024) I've learnt about sub-replace expressions (`:help sub-replace-expression`)

The command that does exactly what I need is:

```
:%s/\(.\+\) \(\d\+\)$/\=substitute(submatch(1), ' ', ' {' . submatch(2) . '}', 'g')/
```

> In the replacement part we use the special operator `\=` which tells Vim to *treat everything that follows as an expression, evaluate it, and use the result as the replacement of the matched text*

Thanks https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/20706/9024