# Replace a character multiple times but within pattern

Tags: search, replace

I am creating a yml file out of some variables.
I have like 80 lines and they all have the pattern:

```
my-first-command-line-var: {{ my-first-command-line-var }},
my-second-cli-var: {{ {{ my-second-cli-var }} ,
my-third-var: {{ my-third-var }}
```

and so on

That's because all cli variables are with `-` but yaml can't handle `_`.

So I need to replace all `-` inside `{{  }}`  with a `_`, so it becomes:

```
my-first-command-line-var: {{ my_first_command_line_var }},
my-second-cli-var: {{ {{ my_second_cli_var }} ,
my-third-var: {{ my_third_var }}
```

I have tried `:%s/{{\zs\-*ze}}/_/g` and some variations like `:%s/{{\zs\(-\)*ze}}/_/g` but nothing like this worked.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34601909/169252 This had a valid solution which worked for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `:s` command with an expression on the replacement side (see [`:help sub-replace-expression`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#sub-replace-expression)), then you can use the [`substitute()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#substitute%28%29) function to perform the replacement of `-` for `_`, and the [`submatch()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#submatch%28%29) function to refer to the match.

For your specific case, the following command will work:

```
:%s/{{.*}}/\=substitute(submatch(0), "-", "_", "g")
```

This will match the contents in between `{{` and `}}` on every line. And it will replace it with the result of the function call, which takes the matched contents (as `submatch(0)`) and replaces all `-`s with `_`s.

Comment: I like this one, because it is basically readable and understandable what's going on - although not so easy to remember

Comment: @transient_loop A slightly deeper dive into sub-replace expressions along with a couple examples that may help with remembering the format:  [How to run a substitute command on only a certain part of the line](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/20706)