# VI replacing 1 character between two double quotes

Tags: replace

I have a 200,000+ line file that I need to update.

My issue is that I need to use commas to separate the fields; however in the original file there are commas placed in the "comment section."  The comment section is delimited by `""`.  Not all lines have this comment field populated and it may not contain any commas.

So when using `awk` with `-F,` my columns are skewed due to the commas in the comment section.

Here is an example of a line in my file:

```
XX,YYY,ZZZ,XXXX,Y,,,QQQQ,AAAA,BBBBB,,,XXX,YYY,,,,,ZZZ,QQ,AAAAAA,YY,ZZZZZZZZ,"Zona Industriale, Via Golgi snc",QQ.ZZZZZZZZ,QQ.ZZZZZZ,31.5,2,0,MACRO,#N/A
```

In the above I need to replace:
`"Zona **Industriale, Via Golgi snc"`
with
`"Zona **Industriale Via Golgi snc"`

So long story short the `,` needs to be removed between the `""`s in the line above and in about 70% of the existing file.

Comment: Welome to [vi.se]! I've [edit]ed your question for formatting and clarity. Please check that it still retains the meaning you wanted.

Comment: If using `awk` on a CSV file is your goal, then see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12956933/9447571) about using GNU awk and FPAT to recognize quoted fields even if they include commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied your example line in a test and found a search and replace command that will find your commas within quotes and delete them.

```
%s/".*\zs,\ze.*"/
```

The breakdown:

- `%s/` for performing the search
- `"` for the beginning of your comment
- `.*` for any number of any characters
- `\zs` for the command to start the match
- `,` for the comma in question
- `\ze` for the command to end the match
- `.*` for any number of any characters
- `"` for the ending of your comment
- `/` and nothing after the slash because you just want it deleted.

It worked for me, let me know if it doesn't work for you.

## Update:

After doing some more searching, it looks like this is the correct answer for multiple replacements:

`%s/"\([^"]|""\)*"/\=substitute(submatch(0), ",", " ", "g")/g`

Which searches for everything between quotes, and then calls the substitute command to submatch 0 which is everything contained in the previous search command, the next argument is the string to search for, the third argument is what to replace it with, and I believe the last argument is to make it global for the file.

[Taken from this previous vi/vim question.](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/27853/replace-a-character-multiple-times-but-within-pattern)

Comment: This only handles a single comma in the quotes; you would need multiple applications to get the rest.

Comment: I tested it by putting multiple commas inside the quote and the command found them all and deleted them.  I wondered if it would.

Comment: Never mind, you're correct, I didn't see the remaining ones clearly.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response... tried it and all looks good, there is some additional massaging that needs to be done but outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Welcome!  I tried to make sure it worked for multiple entries, because that seemed reasonable and thought it did, but it didn't.  You can use `@:` and specify a count to use the previous search command multiple times, which _might_ help speed things up.

Comment: Also, if this is from an AWK command, and your comment line is always in a specific field, you can print the first section of non-comment columns, print the comment column by changing the field separator value to be `"`, and then change it back to be a space for the rest of the columns.  But that's outside the scope of the Vi/Vim Stack Exchange I'd say.

Comment: Thank you for all of your comments and suggestions.  To get the output that I desired it took multiple steps.  In some of the lines there were multiple occurrences of "", so the first suggestion was great answer to the question that I asked, but I did not realize that on line 150345 there were multiple sets of "".  I needed to do some thing like grep out all the lines with "'s in them to a file and see how I could manipulate the data.  I was doing replacement of ""'' with ??'s and then when I got down to just one set of "" per line I could do the replacement as suggested, Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If all the lines have at most one `""` field, you could try

```
global/"/normal! f"f,x
```

and repeat (`@:` the first repeat, then `@@` for the rest, with a count if you like) until the commas are gone.

But I would really suggest using an actual CSV parser; e.g., python's `pandas` library could do something like

```python
data = pandas.read_csv(..., names=[...])
data['comments'].apply(lambda f: f.replace(',', ''))
data.to_csv(...)
```

Thought at that point, you might as well admit you cannot parse a CSV with `awk -F,`…

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, I failed to share that some of the lines have multiple fields that have the " ".  I will be trying your suggestion once I have time to play a bit.  Thank you again for your suggestion!