# Multiple or divide number under cursor with given amount and replace it with the result

Tags: neovim

I can increment the number under the cursor (by e.g. 10) by doing

10`<C-a>`

But how do I multiply the number under the cursor with x amount and the replace it in the same way I do when incrementing by a constant amount?

Answer (score 3):

There's no magic, single operation for arithmetic. You can use substitution with [*sub-replace* expression](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#sub-replace-expression). This will replace all numbers on the current line with their value multiplied by 5.

```
s/\d\+/\=submatch(0)*5/
```

The `\=` operator tells Vim to treat everything that follows as an expression, evaluate it, and use the result as the replacement of the final matched text. And when `submatch(0)` is evaluated it returns whatever the pattern on the left matched. I'm multiplying that by 5, as I mentioned.

Tune the pattern part as needed for your particular situation. I'm matching any numbers but you could just put `10` there though that's not particularly useful for general needs. If there are other things on the line that you want to ignore you could use `\zs` and `\ze` to isolate a number. This one will only effect a number that follows a colon at the beginning of the line:

```
s/^:\zs\d\+\ze/\=submatch(0)*5/
```

Rather than describe in detail how sub-replace expressions generally work in this space you can look at my answer here:
[How to run a substitute command on only a certain part of the line](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/20704/how-to-run-a-substitute-command-on-only-a-certain-part-of-the-line/20706#20706)

Comment: Dont you need a string to number conversion on submatch? Or are you relying on implicit coercions?

Comment: I am converting. Somewhere in the docs there are instructions on how to convert a string to a number. Something like `"100" + 0 => 100`, i.e. arithmetic is pretty explicit conversion.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following to reimplement a mechanism similar to `<c-a>` but for multiplication:

```
function! MultiplyInPlace(count) abort
    " Get the word under the cursor
    let current_word = expand('<cword>')

    " If we don't match a number return
    if (current_word !~ '\d\+')
        return
    endif

    " Get cursor position
    let col = getcurpos()[2]


    " Calculate the result and replace in buffer
    let res = current_word * a:count
    execute 's/\%' . col . 'c' . current_word . '/' . res 

    " Move back to the number we changed
    normal! g``
endfunction

" Use [count]<leader><c-x> to multiply number under cursor by [count]
nnoremap <silent> <leader><c-x> :<C-U>call MultiplyInPlace(v:count1)<CR>
```

The idea is to create a function `MultiplyInPlace()` which takes a count as argument. The function will use [`:h <cword>`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#%3ccword%3e) to get the word under the cursor and match it against `/\d\+/` to make sure it's a number ([`:h expr-=~`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#expr-%3d%7e)).

If it's a number a simple multiplication is done and we use a substitute command forged with `execute` to do the replacement. ([`:h :execute`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#%3Aexecute)).

In the substitute command get use the [`:h /\%c`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2f%5c%25c) atom to match the current column of the cursor to avoid the bug described by @Benji in their comment on this answer.

The last line is needed to avoid the cursor jumping at the beginning of the line. ([`:h g``](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#g%60))

Then you can create a normal mode mapping (here `<leader><c-x>`) which will take a count and call the function with it (and use 1) if no count is provided. ([`:h v:count`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#v%3Acount))

You can then adapt the code pretty simply to also handle the divisions (either create a second function `DivideInPlace()` or add a new argument to `MultiplyInPlace()` to switch between behaviors).

Comment: There is a bug in the above.  Because of the way `s` is used to replace the word, if there are two of the same numbers on the line, the first will be replaced even if the cursor is over the second.

Comment: That's true thanks @BenjiYork for pointing that out. I edited my answer: By using `getcurpos()` to get the column where the cursor is and using `/\%c` in the pattern I think the bug is fixed.