# Substitute in multiple isolated parts of a string

Tags: regular-expression

I have this string:

```
b'32^"Strings" c32 d32 c32 b32 r8. \break
```

I want to replace `[a-z]` (except `r`) with `r` and remove `'` everywhere outside `".."`. I want to ignore `\break`.

Final output should be:

```
r32^"Strings" r32 r32 r32 r32 r8. \break
```

The tricky part is sometimes the `".."` and/or `\break` may not be present.

For example:

```
b'32 c32 d32 c32 b32 a32 g32 fis32 d'32 \break
```

Should be converted to:

```
r32 r32 r32 r32 r32 r32 r32 r32 r32 \break
```

A single command would be desirable, but multiple commands are acceptable too.

I tried:

```
s/^\(.\{-}\)\ze".*$/\=substitute(submatch(1), "[a-z']", 'r', 'g')/
```

and

```
s/^.*"\zs\(.*\)/\=substitute(submatch(1), "[a-z]", "r", "g")/
```

But I am not sure how to handle optional `".."` and `\break`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would propose you:

```
s/\v(<[a-z]'?|"[^"]*"|\\\w+)/\=submatch(1)[0]=='"'||submatch(1)[0]=='\'?submatch(1):'r'/g
```

The idea is to match by token either:

- starting with a letter and an optional quote: `[a-z]'?`
- a quoted string: `"[^"]*"`
- a back-slashed word: `\\\w+`

Then to decide to make the replacement by `r` only on the first case.

i.e.: if the token is not a string or a back-slashed word (`submatch(1)[0]=='"'||submatch(1)[0]=='\'`)

Remark: the leading `\v` allow to clarify the expression avoiding to have to escape the special characters: `<`, `(`, `)`, `|`, `?`, `+` (`[`, `]` and `*` don't need to be escaped).

Comment: Make sure to add the `g` flag to the end of the command